# slice pandas series by set number of rows from a specific index

Tags: python, pandas

consider the `pd.Series` `s`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tidx = pd.date_range('2012-12-31', periods=261)
s = pd.Series(np.arange(len(tidx)), tidx)
```

Suppose I want to get a 14 period window ending at date `'2013-02-22'`

I'd expect the result to be

```
2013-02-09    40
2013-02-10    41
2013-02-11    42
2013-02-12    43
2013-02-13    44
2013-02-14    45
2013-02-15    46
2013-02-16    47
2013-02-17    48
2013-02-18    49
2013-02-19    50
2013-02-20    51
2013-02-21    52
2013-02-22    53
Freq: D, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To [avoid chained indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy),
you could use `s.index.get_loc` to find the positional index associated with `2013-02-22` and the use `iloc` with the positional index to make the selection:

```
In [93]: i = s.index.get_loc('2013-02-22')+1; s.iloc[i-14:i]
Out[93]: 
2013-02-09    40
2013-02-10    41
2013-02-11    42
2013-02-12    43
2013-02-13    44
2013-02-14    45
2013-02-15    46
2013-02-16    47
2013-02-17    48
2013-02-18    49
2013-02-19    50
2013-02-20    51
2013-02-21    52
2013-02-22    53
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [12]: s.ix[:'2013-02-22'].iloc[-14:]
Out[12]:
2013-02-09    40
2013-02-10    41
2013-02-11    42
2013-02-12    43
2013-02-13    44
2013-02-14    45
2013-02-15    46
2013-02-16    47
2013-02-17    48
2013-02-18    49
2013-02-19    50
2013-02-20    51
2013-02-21    52
2013-02-22    53
Freq: D, dtype: int32
```